# How to pass a url containing slashes as a path parameter in GO?

Tags: go

I want to send an url such as "Documents/folder1/folder2/file.txt" or it can have less slashes such as "Documents/folder1/file.txt", and I want to pass this url as a path parameter, such as `router.HandleFunc("/myproject/v1/image/{url}", GetImage)`

but when doing this it treats to go to the url for ex: /myproject/v1/image/Documents/folder1/file.txt and it does not find it so it returns 404.

I am using gorilla mux:

```
func main(){
   router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
   router.HandleFunc("/myproject/v1/image/{url}", GetImage)
}
```

I thought  that it was from the strictslash but when I set it false I remain getting 404

Answer (score 1):

`StrictSlashes` has to do with a single trailing slash, not with whether or not slashes are matched inside of a parameter (they aren't). You need to use [`PathPrefix`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Route.PathPrefix):

```
const (
    imagesPrefix = "/myproject/v1/image/"  // note no {url}
)

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    router.PathPrefix(imagesPrefix).Handler(
        http.StripPrefix(imagesPrefix, GetHandler),
    )
}

func GetImage (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // r.URL.Path should contain the image path.
}
```